# MouseListener to Instance of Game Panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouselistener

I'm creating a Tic Tac Toe game where I'm using MouseListener to add functionality to my game panel. When a user clicks one of the cells its suppose to generate an X or O graphic depending on whose turn it is. I've tried adding the MouseListener to the pane, but when I run it nothing happens when I click. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Here's my game panel:

```java
public GameMain() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        this.addMouseListener(handler);

        // setup JLabel
        label = new JLabel("         ");
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 5, 4, 5));
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT + 30));
        board = new Board();
        initGame();

    }   
}
```

Here's my Handler class with the mouseClick() method that's suppose to run:

```java
public class Handler extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClick(MouseEvent e) {
            int mouseX = e.getX();
            int mouseY = e.getY();

            // Get the row and column clicked
            int rowSelected = mouseY / CELL_SIZE;
            int colSelected = mouseX / CELL_SIZE;

            if (currentState == GameState.PLAYING) {
                if (rowSelected >= 0 && rowSelected < board.cells.length && colSelected >= 0 && colSelected < board.cells.length &&  
                    board.cells[rowSelected][colSelected].content == Seed.EMPTY) {
                    board.cells[rowSelected][colSelected].content = currentPlayer; // move
                    updateGame(currentPlayer, rowSelected, colSelected); // update currentState
                    currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == Seed.X) ? Seed.O : Seed.X;
                }
            } else {
                initGame();
            }

            repaint();
        }

        public void handleButtonPress(Object o) {
            if (o == singlePlayer) {
                singlePlayerGame();
            }
            if (o == multiPlayer) {
                multiPlayerGame();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: What is the parent class of your `GameMain` class?

Comment: @abra I have it extended to JPanel

Comment: @abra I probably would've gone the direction of using JButtons instead, but my assignment requires us to go the JPanel route, unfortunately.

Comment: Post a proper [mre]. We don't know what the context of your code is. I see a class called Board which I would guess is your game panel. Therefore the MouseListener should be added to that class and NOT the frame. Also, you may want to handle mouseReleased instead of mouseClicked because if you move your mouse 1 pixel between the mousePressed and mouseReleased events it will not register as a click.

Comment: @Abra *By default, JPanel is not focusable* - correct.  *hence it won't notify mouse listeners* - incorrect. Mouse events will be passed to the panel, however the panel won't gain focus for example by tabbing.

Comment: Still doesn't change my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question inspired me to take up the challenge of writing a tic-tac-toe game, since I don't have much experience in handling custom painting. The below code is copiously commented, so I hope that those comments will serve as a good explanation of the code.

I'm presuming that people with more experience than me will find flaws in the below code, which is to be expected, since, as I already mentioned, I don't have a lot of experience in this kind of programming. Nonetheless, I hope it is good enough in order to be of help you.

Note that the below code makes use of a new java feature that was introduced with JDK 14, namely [Records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359). Hence it may also be helpful to people as a simple example of how to integrate java records into their code. If you aren't using JDK 14 or if you are but you haven't enabled [preview features](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/preview-language-and-vm-features.html), you can simply replace the record definition with a simple class. Just replace the word `record` with `class` and add a constructor and "getter" methods to the code. By default, the name of a "getter" method in a `record` is simply the name of the field, e.g. for member `minX` in record `Square` (in below code), the "getter" method is `minX()`.

```java
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * A simple tic-tac-toe (a.k.a. noughts and crosses) game. User clicks mouse on an empty square of
 * the game board and either a nought or a cross is drawn in that square, depending on whose turn
 * it is. Each square has an index as shown below.
 * <pre>
 * 0    1   2
 * 
 * 3    4   5
 * 
 * 6    7   8
 * </pre>
 * See <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe">Tic-tac-toe</a> on <i>Wikipedia</i>.
 */
public class GameMain extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener, Runnable {

    /** For serializing instances of this class. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7014608855599083001L;

    /** A cross. */
    private static final char  CROSS = 'X';

    /** A nought. */
    private static final char  NOUGHT = 'O';

    /** Dimension of each square in tic-tac-toe board. */
    private static final int  SQUARE_DIMENSION = 80;

    /** Number of consecutive squares required for a win. */
    private static final int  REQUIRED_SQUARES = 3;

    /** Total number of squares in tic-tac-toe board. */
    private static final int  TOTAL_SQUARES = 9;

    /** Each of the 9 squares in tic-tac-toe board. */
    private final Square[]  SQUARES = new Square[]{new Square(1, 1, 99, 99),
                                                   new Square(101, 1, 199, 99),
                                                   new Square(201, 1, 299, 99),

                                                   new Square(1, 101, 99, 199),
                                                   new Square(101, 101, 199, 199),
                                                   new Square(201, 101, 299, 199),

                                                   new Square(1, 201, 99, 299),
                                                   new Square(101, 201, 199, 299),
                                                   new Square(201, 201, 299, 299)};

    /** Text for {@link #turnLabel} at start of a new tic-tac-toe game. */
    private static final String  FIRST_MOVE = "X goes first";

    /** Text for <i>new game</i>. button. */
    private static final String  NEW_GAME = "New Game";

    /** Indicates start of a new game. */
    private boolean  newGame;

    /** <tt>true</tt> means O turn and <tt>false</tt> means X turn. */
    private boolean  oTurn;

    /** Records occupied squares, either &apos;O&apos; or &apos;X&apos; */
    private char[]  occupied = new char[TOTAL_SQUARES];

    /** Number of unoccupied squares in tic-tac-toe board. */
    private int  freeCount;

    /** Displays whose turn it currently is. */
    private JLabel  turnLabel;

    /** Location of last mouse click. */
    private Point  clickPoint;

    /**
     * Creates and returns instance of this class.
     */
    public GameMain() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        addMouseListener(this);
        freeCount = TOTAL_SQUARES;
    }

    private static boolean isValidRequirement(int index) {
        return index >= 0  &&  index < REQUIRED_SQUARES;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether <var>square</var> is a valid index of a square in tic-tac-toe board.
     * 
     * @param square - will be validated.
     * 
     * @return  <tt>true</tt> if <var>square</var> is valid.
     */
    private static boolean isValidSquare(int square) {
        return square >= 0  &&  square < TOTAL_SQUARES;
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionEvent
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actnEvnt) {
        String actionCommand = actnEvnt.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case NEW_GAME:
                startNewGame();
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                                              actionCommand,
                                              "Unhandled",
                                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.MouseListener
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mousEvnt) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.MouseListener
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mousEvnt) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.MouseListener
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mousEvnt) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.MouseListener
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mousEvnt) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.MouseListener
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mousEvnt) {
        System.out.println("mouse clicked");
        clickPoint = mousEvnt.getPoint();
        repaint();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            String text;
            if (isWinner()) {
                text = oTurn ? "O has won!" : "X has won!";
                removeMouseListener(this);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                                              text,
                                              "Winner",
                                              JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
            else if (freeCount <= 0) {
                text = "Drawn game.";
                removeMouseListener(this);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                                              text,
                                              "Draw",
                                              JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
            else {
                oTurn = !oTurn;
                text = oTurn ? "O's turn" : "X's turn";
            }
            turnLabel.setText(text);
        });
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    @Override // javax.swing.JComponent
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawLine(100, 0, 100, 300);
        g2d.drawLine(200, 0, 200, 300);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 100, 300, 100);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 200, 300, 200);
        if (!newGame) {
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                                 RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
            for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_SQUARES; i++) {
                if (occupied[i] == NOUGHT) {
                    drawNought(i, g2d);
                }
                else if (occupied[i] == CROSS) {
                    drawCross(i, g2d);
                }
            }
            int square = getSquare(clickPoint);
            if (isFreeSquare(square)) {
                if (oTurn) {
                    drawNought(square, g2d);
                    occupied[square] = NOUGHT;
                }
                else {
                    drawCross(square, g2d);
                    occupied[square] = CROSS;
                }
                freeCount--;
            }
        }
        else {
            newGame = false;
        }
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("O & X");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTurnPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text, int mnemonic, String tooltip) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        if (mnemonic > 0) {
            button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        }
        if (tooltip != null  &&  !tooltip.isBlank()) {
            button.setToolTipText(tooltip);
        }
        button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 0, 0, 0, Color.GRAY));
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton(NEW_GAME, KeyEvent.VK_N, "Start a new game."));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createTurnPanel() {
        JPanel turnPanel = new JPanel();
        turnPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, Color.GRAY));
        turnLabel = new JLabel(FIRST_MOVE);
        turnPanel.add(turnLabel);
        return turnPanel;
    }

    /**
     * Draws a {@link #CROSS} in <var>square</var> of tic-tac-toe board.
     * 
     * @param square - index of square in tic-tac-toe board.
     * @param g2d    - facilitates drawing.
     */
    private void drawCross(int square, Graphics2D g2d) {
        if (isValidSquare(square)  &&  g2d != null) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.drawLine(SQUARES[square].minX() + 10,
                         SQUARES[square].minY() + 10,
                         SQUARES[square].maxX() - 10,
                         SQUARES[square].maxY() - 10);
            g2d.drawLine(SQUARES[square].maxX() - 10,
                         SQUARES[square].minY() + 10,
                         SQUARES[square].minX() + 10,
                         SQUARES[square].maxY() - 10);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Draws a {@link #NOUGHT} in <var>square</var> of tic-tac-toe board.
     * 
     * @param square - index of square in tic-tac-toe board.
     * @param g2d    - facilitates drawing.
     */
    private void drawNought(int square, Graphics2D g2d) {
        if (isValidSquare(square)  &&  g2d != null) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawOval(SQUARES[square].minX() + 10,
                         SQUARES[square].minY() + 10,
                         SQUARE_DIMENSION,
                         SQUARE_DIMENSION);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the square of the tic-tac-toe board that contains <var>pt</var>.
     * 
     * @param pt - point on tic-tac-toe board.
     * 
     * @return  index of square in tic-tac-toe board containing <var>pt</var> or -1 (negative one)
     *          if <var>pt</var> not in tic-tac-toe board.
     * 
     * @see Square#contains(int, int)
     */
    private int getSquare(Point pt) {
        int ndx = -1;
        if (pt != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (SQUARES[i].contains(pt.x, pt.y)) {
                    ndx = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return ndx;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether <var>column</var> of tic-tac-toe board contains all {@link #CROSS} or all
     * {@link #NOUGHT}.
     * 
     * @param column - index of column in tic-tac-toe board.
     * 
     * @return  <tt>true</tt> if <var>column</var> contains all {@link #CROSS} or all {@link #NOUGHT}.
     * 
     * @see #isValidRequirement(int)
     */
    private boolean isColumnWin(int column) {
        boolean isWin = false;
        if (isValidRequirement(column)) {
            isWin = isOccupied(column)  &&
                    occupied[column] == occupied[column + REQUIRED_SQUARES]  &&
                    occupied[column] == occupied[column + (REQUIRED_SQUARES * 2)];
        }
        return isWin;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether diagonal of tic-tac-toe board contains all {@link #CROSS} or all
     * {@link #NOUGHT}. The board contains precisely two diagonals where each one includes the
     * board&apos;s center square, i.e. the square with index 4. The other squares that constitute
     * diagonals are the corner squares, including the indexes 0 (zero), 2, 6 and 8.
     * 
     * @return  <tt>true</tt> if one of the tic-tac-toe board diagonals contains all {@link #CROSS}
     *          or all {@link #NOUGHT}.
     * 
     * @see #isValidRequirement(int)
     */
    private boolean isDiagonalWin() {
        boolean isWin = false;
        isWin = (isOccupied(0)  &&
                occupied[0] == occupied[4]  &&
                occupied[0] == occupied[8])
                ||
                (isOccupied(2)  &&
                 occupied[2] == occupied[4]  &&
                 occupied[2] == occupied[6]);
        return isWin;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether <var>square</var> in tic-tac-toe board does not contain a {@link #CROSS}
     * nor a {@link #NOUGHT}.
     * 
     * @param square - index of square in tic-tac-toe board.
     * 
     * @return  <tt>true</tt> if <var>square</var> does not contain a {@link #CROSS} nor a {@link
     *          #NOUGHT}.
     */
    private boolean isFreeSquare(int square) {
        boolean freeSquare = false;
        if (isValidSquare(square)) {
            freeSquare = occupied[square] != CROSS  &&  occupied[square] != NOUGHT;
        }
        return freeSquare;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether <var>row</var> of tic-tac-toe board contains all {@link #CROSS} or all
     * {@link #NOUGHT}.
     * 
     * @param row - index of row in tic-tac-toe board.
     * 
     * @return  <tt>true</tt> if <var>row</var> contains all {@link #CROSS} or all {@link #NOUGHT}.
     * 
     * @see #isValidRequirement(int)
     */
    private boolean isLineWin(int row) {
        boolean isWin = false;
        if (isValidRequirement(row)) {
            int index = row * REQUIRED_SQUARES;
            isWin = isOccupied(index)  &&
                    occupied[index] == occupied[index + 1]  &&
                    occupied[index] == occupied[index + 2];
        }
        return isWin;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether square at <var>index</var> in tic-tac-toe board contains either a {@link
     * #CROSS} or a {@link #NOUGHT}.
     * 
     * @param index - index of square in tic-tac-toe board.
     * 
     * @return  <tt>true</tt> if square at <var>index</var> in tic-tac-toe board contains either a
     *          {@link #CROSS} or a {@link #NOUGHT}.
     * 
     * @see #isValidSquare(int)
     */
    private boolean isOccupied(int index) {
        boolean occupied = false;
        if (isValidSquare(index)) {
            occupied = this.occupied[index] == CROSS  ||  this.occupied[index] == NOUGHT;
        }
        return occupied;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if there is a winner.
     * 
     * @return  <tt>true</tt> if someone has won the game.
     * 
     * @see #isColumnWin(int)
     * @see #isDiagonalWin()
     * @see #isLineWin(int)
     */
    private boolean isWinner() {
        return isLineWin(0)   ||
               isLineWin(1)   ||
               isLineWin(2)   ||
               isColumnWin(0) ||
               isColumnWin(1) ||
               isColumnWin(2) ||
               isDiagonalWin();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the GUI in order to start a new game.
     */
    private void startNewGame() {
        freeCount = TOTAL_SQUARES;
        newGame = true;
        oTurn = false;
        occupied = new char[TOTAL_SQUARES];
        repaint();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            removeMouseListener(this);
            addMouseListener(this);
            turnLabel.setText(FIRST_MOVE);
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method is the first one called when this class is launched via the <tt>java</tt>
     * command. It ignores the method parameter <var>args</var>.
     * 
     * @param args - <tt>java</tt> command arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new GameMain());
    }
}

/**
 * Represents the geometrical shape known as a square. For the purposes of this {@code record}, a
 * square is defined by two points that indicate its top, left corner and its bottom, right corner.
 */
record Square (int minX, int minY, int maxX, int maxY) {

    /**
     * Determines whether the supplied point lies within this square.
     * 
     * @param x - x coordinate of a point.
     * @param y - y coordinate of same point (as x).
     * 
     * @return  <tt>true</tt> if supplied point lies within this square.
     */
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        return minX <= x  &&  x <= maxX  &&  minY <= y  &&  y <= maxY;
    }
}
```